# Java on Mac: Keyboard commands from screen menubar not executed

Tags: java, macos, swing

Using Java 8 with Swing on a Mac, I'm having a JMenuBar in a JFrame which is placed as a screen menu bar using the system property `apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar`.

When I open a child dialog inside this JFrame, I should be able to access my menu commands via their shortcuts. When hitting my shortcut (Command +Z) The menubar flashes, but the command is not executed. Any suggestions?

Here a code snippet to run the problem. Pressing Command+Z in the main JFrame works and executes the action. Pressing Command +Z inside the child window doesn't work.

```
public class TestClass {

    static class MyFrame extends JFrame {

        public MyFrame() throws HeadlessException {
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu menu = new JMenu("menu");
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("action") {
                {
                    putValue(AbstractAction.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
                }

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("action executed!");
                }
            });
            menu.add(menuItem);
            menuBar.add(menu);
            setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            JButton button = new JButton("open dialog");
            add(button);
            button.addActionListener((e) -> {
                JDialog dlg = new JDialog(MyFrame.this);
                dlg.setSize(300, 300);
                dlg.setVisible(true);
            });
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: You may be looking  for `Application::setDefaultMenuBar` examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37297645/230513).

Comment: This command sets a menu bar, when no other menu bar is set by any window. Doesn't work any better, the menu command is never accessable via the keyboard command on my computer then.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm not sure I would expect the frame's menu actions to work when the modeless dialog has focus. I think that's what the flash is meant to indicate.

Comment: The flash indicates on Mac, that a command has been executed from the menu bar. So this works correctly.

Comment: I'm not seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with a JFrame on macOS (jdk1.8.0_201). Symptoms:

- menus work fine with a mouse, and menu shortcuts are visible on the menu items
- when the shortcut keys are pressed, the menu heading flashes but no ActionEvent is triggered

I eventually figured out the issue was caused by overriding `java.lang.Object`'s `hashCode()` method on the JFrame. Why this causes keyboard shortcuts to fail is unknown to me, but it is definitively the root cause in my case.